# Create dataframe with labels sorted according to data

Tags: python, pandas

**Edit:** I edited the example because the previous one could be interpreted in different ways.

I have a dataframe with row labels and in each column a sorting of the labels:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'0': [3,1,2], '1': [2,3,1]}, index=['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'])
```

It looks like this (real data has more columns):

[image: d]

I want to transform it into a matrix with color names sorted according to the ranks in each column.

For example, the first column is `[3, 2, 1]` and the result should be `['Blue', 'Green', 'Red']`.

The second column is `[2, 3, 1]` and the result should be `['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']`.

The numbers are the rank of each label in that column. (They are **not** indices into the labels array.) So if 'Red' has 2, it means it should be in the second cell in the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) per columns in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().index)
print (df1)
           0      1
Red     Blue   Blue
Green  Green    Red
Blue     Red  Green
```

Comment: I fixed my example which could be interpreted in 2 different ways. The numbers are not indices into the labels array. They are the rank of each label in that column. So if 'Red' has 2, it means it should be in the second cell in the column.

Comment: @daramasala - Is possible change data sample for see data not working with my solution? Because now, data description and also expected output not match(`['Green', 'Red', 'Green']`)

Comment: you are right. I fixed the example. For `[2, 3, 1]` it should `['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']` (red is 2nd, green is 3rd, blue is 1st)

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I think it does the same thing only in a different way, no? It uses the numbers as indexes into the index array. But this is not what I want. I want to sort the labels according to the rank in the cell. So if a '2' appears in the 'Red' row, I want 'Red' to be the 2nd element, not to replace the '2' with the 2nd row label.

Comment: @daramasala - simpliest is use `arr = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().index)`

Comment: Thanks! If you update your answer I will select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I am sure there are better solutions:

```py
# Construct the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [3,1,2], '1': [2,3,1]}, index=['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'])
# Prepare an empty numpy array to hold the answer
a = np.empty([3, 2], dtype=np.dtype('U20'))
# Extract the index labels and duplicate them to match the shape of the answer
index = np.array([df.index.to_numpy(), ]* 2).transpose()
# Get the ranks as a numpy array
ranks = (df.astype('int') -1).to_numpy()
# Use the ranks as the indices in the target array for each label 
np.put_along_axis(a, ranks, index, 0)
```